# Will the experimental Monero Trezor firmware continue to work after January?

Tags: monerod, trezor

In January, Monero will hard-fork to begin to support RingCT (optionally until September). It will also introduce dynamic fee transactions.

The existing monero trezor firmware does not support dynamic fee transactions, nor does it support RingCT transactions. Will transactions generated via the Monero Trezor firmware be rejected by the monero network due to an incompatible fee structure? Or will it continue to be useful until the September hardfork when RingCT transactions become mandatory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RingCT is not mandatory until September 2017.  Compiled [v0.10.1](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/v0.10.1) last night, and [**V0313** experimental Trezor](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing) still saw the proper balance with the new node. Have not tested sending a new transaction yet. Without the guru, we will probably need to wait until 2017-01-10 before we know the truth.

Be sure you have tested the conversion of 24 BIP 39 seed words to Electrum seed words to recover without the need for a Trezor. Test the recovery process in advance. I'm sticking with [V0313](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing) with a **simplewallet --hardware-wallet 0** until judgement time.

Read **NoodleDoodle's** comments [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5cblwf/ledger_nano_s_hardware_support/), the Monero H/W wallet guru.

The edit dEBRUYNE recommended below to Monero v0.10.1 source code appears to breathe new life into Trezor **V0313** Monero firmware. This has the potential to be a stop gap solution that might last until September 2017.

**10 January 2017 Update:**  HARD FORK DEFINITELY BROKE TREZOR V0313 FUNCTIONALITY.
`[4NoT0K]: refresh
Starting refresh...
Error: refresh failed: refresh error: block parse error. Blocks received: 0
Error: block parse error Blocks received: 0
Error: block parse error Blocks received: 0
Error: block parse error Blocks received: 0
Error: block parse error Blocks received: 0`

Comment: Could you let us know if sending works? If not, could you try sending with a compiled daemon that removes `|| req.do_not_relay` from [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/rpc/core_rpc_server.cpp#L557) line?

Comment: Reconstruction of the Electrum seed words  using  ```"./trezorctl recover_mnemonic 0 "" English" 24_BIP39_words``` worked fine for seeding ```./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet```.  Sent a transaction from a Trezor.  The signed transaction is hung in a pool after an hour's wait. Will wait until tomorrow before recompiling.  Noticed a few transactions in the past took the better part of a day to clear in the past.

Comment: Had to perform **rescan_bc** to unstick the Trezor transaction that never cleared after 12 hours. ```Recompiled code as requested.``` A Trezor transaction successfully completed within a few minutes when using **transaction_new** with a mixin of 3:-)

Comment: Good to hear. What does `transaction_new` mean though? Simply a transaction performed with the "adjusted" daemon?

Comment: Brain fart, meant  ```transfer_new``` that is visible within the V0313 simplewallet when one issues a ```help```.

Comment: Ah makes sense!